# Do I need to install awk or is it inbuilt in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, awk

I'm new to Linux OS and studying Mobile Computing. I have to analyze files using `awk`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Do I need to install `awk` or is it inbuilt in Ubuntu?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 14.04, why didn't you just run `awk` in a terminal and see for yourself?

Comment: Yes its Working . I tried awk '/some_word/ {print}' file_name

Comment: You can test whether awk or any other software is installed by doing `which awk`.  It will either return the path to the exe or return nothing.

Answer (score 24):

Ubuntu's desktop edition has [`mawk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mawk.1) installed by default, as it's a dependency of [the `lsb-core` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/lsb-core). It conforms to standard AWK, with a few extensions.

[GNU `awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/gawk.1.html), which has more features, needs to be installed separately:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

Comment: Side note - because gnu awk has more features, some of the functions are present only in gnu awk, not mawk. So some code may be incompatible. But for simple code any version will do.